# Unable to uninstall snap package

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to uninstall heroku installed via snap but I got stuck with the following error

> snap "heroku" has "auto-refresh" change in progress

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

I have googled the issue and the results were not helpful. Can someone help

Answer (score 1):

You can add the parameter "now" to the end of your command, it will ignore the "auto-refresh".

example:

```
sudo snap remove heroku now
```